# Winforms datagridview : drag and drop causes an error

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, drag-and-drop, bindinglist

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional Information : Rows cannot be programmatically removed unless the DataGridView is data-bound to an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows delete

This is how I bind my data to datagridview :

```
IEnumerable<myTable> query = from p in db.myTables select p;
        testList = query.ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = testList;
```

And this is what I use to drag & drop rows :

```
        private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                rw = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
                rowIndexFromMouseDown = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(rw, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }        
    private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }
    private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        int rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop;
        Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).RowIndex;

        if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndexFromMouseDown);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop, rw);
        }
    }
```

Whenever I tried to drag & drop, dragging is ok but drop causes the error that I mentioned above, and if  possible I dont want to use bindinglist because if I use it I will have to make lots of changes. 
If you can help I would be greateful.

Comment: If you want two-way binding, you'll need to use a binding list.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. 
This is not working
`IEnumerable<EFESRDP0> query = from p in db.EFESRDP0s select p;
            testList = query.ToList();
            var list = new BindingList<EFESRDP0>(testList);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;`

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, although you can try doing some research for an alternative.

Comment: Your bindingList needs to be in a BindingSource like this: `var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = (from p in db.myTables select p).ToBindingList();
dgv1.DataSource = bindingSource;`

Comment: I'm using linq to sql but your proposition requires EF. I cannot apply that because If I do I will have to make changes on my entire project. @SpaceSteak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I've made changes on mouse events

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
        {                
            if (dragBoxFromMouseDown != Rectangle.Empty && !dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y))
            {                                       
                DragDropEffects dropEffect = dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown], DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
    }
    private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the index of the item the mouse is below.
        rowIndexFromMouseDown = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
        if (rowIndexFromMouseDown != -1)
        {                             
            Size dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;
            dragBoxFromMouseDown = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X - (dragSize.Width / 2), e.Y - (dragSize.Height / 2)), dragSize);
        }
        else               
            dragBoxFromMouseDown = Rectangle.Empty;
    }
    private void dataGridView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DataGridViewRow)))
            {
                Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));                   
                if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Copy)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow Row = (DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow));
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Row.Cells[0].Value, Row.Cells[1].Value, Row.Cells[2].Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Reflect the exception to screen
                MessageBox.Show("Geen data! #01", "Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```